# HERE Api - Different route result using iOS/Android SDK and REST API

Tags: ios, here-api

I have some problem with routing and dirt road using the mobile SDK.
Using the following parameter with the REST api the route is calculated:

> maneuverattributes: "direction,action" 
>   mode: "fastest;car;dirtRoad:-3,boatFerry:0" 
>   representation: "display" 
>   routeattributes: "waypoints,summary,shape,legs" 
>   waypoint0: "37.277430,13.572681" 
>   waypoint1: "37.287706,13.817110" 
>   waypoint2: "37.276359,14.097211" 
>   waypoint3: "37.316294,14.130108" 
>   waypoint4: "37.368569,14.334077" 
>   waypoint5: "37.238077,14.512665" 
>   waypoint6: "37.230885,14.538092" 
>   waypoint7: "37.181701,14.772583" 
>   waypoint8: "37.162439,14.751674" 
>   waypoint9: "37.041651,14.795221" 
>   waypoint10: "36.926747,14.747216" 
>   waypoint11: "36.885887,14.686213" 
>   waypoint12: "36.837361,14.606543"

here is an example (replace your app id & code):

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=37.277430%2C13.572681&waypoint1=37.287706%2C13.817110&waypoint2=37.276359%2C14.097211&waypoint3=37.316294%2C14.130108&waypoint4=37.368569%2C14.334077&waypoint5=37.238077%2C14.512665&waypoint6=37.230885%2C14.538092&waypoint7=37.181701%2C14.772583&waypoint8=37.162439%2C14.751674&waypoint9=37.041651%2C14.795221&waypoint10=36.926747%2C14.747216&waypoint11=36.885887%2C14.686213&waypoint12=36.837361%2C14.606543&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled%3BdirtRoad%3A-3&app_id=<YOUR APP ID>&app_code=<YOUR APP CODE>&departure=now
```

The route is the same if I set `dirtRoad:0` or `dirtRoad:-3`

Using the mobile SDK (iOS or Android) I'm getting the following error and the route is not calculated:

> "NMARoutingErrorViolatesOptions"

I'm passing the following parameters (with the same waypoints used in the REST example) to `NMACoreRouter.calculateRoute()` (on iOS as an example)

```
let routingMode = NMARoutingMode()
routingMode.transportMode = .car
routingMode.routingType = .fastest
routingMode.routingOptions = NMARoutingOption.avoidDirtRoad;
```

removing `NMARoutingOption.avoidDirtRoad` the route is calculated, but doing so I think dirt roads are included in the route.
It's a bug? Or the iOS option `NMARoutingOption.avoidDirtRoad` is different from the REST `dirtRoad:-3`? How can i get consistent result on both platform?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In general the algorithm and underlying map data used by the HERE Routing REST API and HERE Mobile SDK are different hence there could always be differences in the route shape. The map update cycles of HERE Routing REST API and HERE Mobile SDK are also slightly different (weekly vs monthly) and unfortunately there is no way to work around it .